# "Uncaught ReferenceError: gotoLogIn is not defined" on PHP calling Javscript function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a web age containing both PHP(7.3) which is first in the file and HTML(5) shown below.

In the PHP, I do the following:

```
echo '<script>gotoLogIn();</script>';
```

In the HTML, I have the following:

```
<script>
function gotoLogIn() {
    alert("Now going elsewhere.");
    window.location.replace("http://localhost/xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/index.php");
}
</script>
```

When the PHP "echo" is executed, I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: gotoLogIn is not defined which shows up on the Firefox Web Console".  I get the same error on Chrome.

I've tried a number of things including the answer to a similar question on SO with no joy.

I am at a loss.  This is the technique I have found in several sites.

Are they old references and is there a newer way to do this or a security action that needs to be taken.

All help appreciated.

Regards,
Jim

Comment: You can use php's `header()`, don't see a reason for doing it from javascript

Comment: Ignore the PHP, and just look at the source code for the browser. Make sure that the function is being defined somewhere on the page

Comment: I agree with @AlonEitan - this is a JavaScript problem but there is no need to use JS for simple redirection.

Comment: In what order do the `<script>` elements appear in the finished HTML that the browser receives? While not precisely the same, the issue might be similar to: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 0):

Well as the others already mentioned you can do it with PHP header (https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.header.php)

```
header("LOCATION: index.php");
```

If you still want to use JavaScript you have to ensure that your function called by php is executed after the Script has been defined within your html.

You can do this the following way have a look at this thread [Pure JavaScript equivalent of jQuery's $.ready() - how to call a function when the page/DOM is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t)

Comment: I appreciate the input but what I showed is just a sample of what I am doing and which is much more than the example.  The redirection is that last step.  The sample is what I am testing with and it does not work.